# How to Get First Object by it's index from below object mentioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need FirstObj by index like I am trying to access it through TestCode[0].List , Please suggest me correct way to access it.

```
'TestCode':{
    'FirstObj':{
        'List':[
            {
                year:2014
            },
            {
                year:2015
            },
            {
                year:2016
            }
         ]
     },
     'SecondObj':{
        'List':[
            {
                year:2014
            },
            {
                year:2015
            },
            {
                year:2016
            }
         ]
     }
}
```

Comment: You have a nested object not an array, so using index accessors will not work. You need to access the object by key.

Comment: but is there any way to get first object without key I this may come dynamically

Comment: @RajanikJarasania I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested object not an array, so using index accessors will not work. You need to access the object by key. You can do this by using `Object.keys` and retrieving the first one from that resulting array:

```js
var data = {
    'TestCode': {
        'FirstObj': {
            'List': [{
                year: 2014
            }, {
                year: 2015
            }, {
                year: 2016
            }]
        },
        'SecondObj': {
            'List': [{
                year: 2014
            }, {
                year: 2015
            }, {
                year: 2016
            }]
        }
    }
}

var keys = Object.keys(data.TestCode);
console.log(data.TestCode[keys[0]].List);
```

Comment: +1, might be worth noting that `Object.keys` [enumerates properties in creation order](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys). (If creating from JSON this shouldn't be an issue though.)

Answer (score 0):

It may be not possible but you can try the logic by using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys),

```
keys = Object.keys(TestCode);
TestCode[keys[0]].List
```

```js
var TestCode ={
    'FirstObj':{
        'List':[
            {
                year:2014
            },
            {
                year:2015
            },
            {
                year:2016
            }
         ]
     },
     'SecondObj':{
        'List':[
            {
                year:2014
            },
            {
                year:2015
            },
            {
                year:2016
            }
         ]
     }
}

keys = Object.keys(TestCode);
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(TestCode[keys[0]].List);
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
```